# #define in macro body

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I have the following use case

```
#define ConstantDouble( T )\
 T( Alert, c_alert )

 // I want to generate #define macro's dynamically
#define T( x, y ) #define #x y   <-- Error
ConstantDouble( T )
#undef T 

#define Constant( x ) Constants::x ;   <-- x is Alert and I want the prev #define to     kick in and convert this to c_alert

// Want to generate members variables directly 
class Constants
{
    #define T( x, y ) static double y;
    ConstantDouble( T )
    #undef T
};
```

This there a workaround for this  ?

I would like to have something like this in my name

`Constant( "Alert" )` which is converted to `Constants::c_alert;`

Comment: This isn't C, it's C++! There are various preprocessor tricks you can do to do things like that in C (look up "xmacros"), but since you're using C++ anyway why not just use templates?

Comment: Could you give an example with templates ?

Comment: I might be able to, but first I'll need you to explain what the purpose of this whole construction is. Why do you want to write `Constant("Alert")` and get `c_alert`?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no workaround. There is exactly one preprocessor pass.

As noted in the comments, C++ templates are far easier. They're compiled by the real compiler, which supports a far more complex grammar, can do math, and can do 255 levels of nesting.